Error routing in Next.JS app-router is not working
I have this File Structure :

"use client";
import { getDebugger } from "@/app/lib/debugger";
import { saveUserAction } from "@/app/lib/actions";
import FormInput from "../../(components)/forms/FormInput";
import SubmitBtn from "../../(components)/forms/SubmitBtn";

const debug = getDebugger("sign-up-form");

const Page = () => {
  function getRandomInt(count: number) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * count);
  }
  const random = getRandomInt(2);

  if (random === 1) {
    throw new Error("error loading");
  }
  return (
    <main>
      <form action={saveUserAction}>
        <FormInput
          name="firstName"
          label="First Name:"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Your First Name"
        />
        <FormInput
          name="lastName"
          label="Last Name:"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Your Last Name"
        />
        <FormInput
          name="password"
          label="Password:"
          type="password"
          placeholder="**"
        />
        <FormInput
          name="confirmPassword"
          label="Confirm Password:"
          type="password"
          placeholder="**"
        />
        <FormInput
          name="email"
          label="Email:"
          type="email"
          placeholder="Your Email Here"
        />
        <SubmitBtn text="Sign Up" />
      </form>
    </main>
  );
};
export default Page;

"use client";

const error = ({ error }: { error: any }) => {
  return (
    <main>
      <h1>Something Wrong...</h1>
      <p>{error}</p>
    </main>
  );
};
export default error;

When I make error inside my auth/sign-up page.tsx I dont get to the error in the root folder.
I dont want to write error.tsx in every folder, I want to have some global Error, so everytime I will have error it will be the error in my folder structure.
Im new to Next.js and I really want to understand why its not working as a global error if its inside my root folder. only when i have error in the main page.tsx I get the error page, but when I have in other folders I don't get to the error page at all.
